# How do I indirectly assign a variable in bash to take multi-line data from both Standard In, a File, and the output of execution

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

I have found many snippets here and in other places that answer parts of this question.  I have even managed to do this in many steps in an inefficient manner.  If it is possible, **I would really like to find single lines of execution that will perform this task**, rather than having to assign to a variable and copy it a few times to perform the task.

e.g.

```
executeToVar ()
{
    # Takes Arg1: NAME OF VARIABLE TO STORE IN
    # All Remaining Arguments Are Executed
    local STORE_INvar="${1}" ; shift
    eval ${STORE_INvar}=\""$( "$@" 2>&1 )"\"
}
```

Overall does work, i.e.  `$ executeToVar SOME_VAR ls -l *  #` will actually fill `SOME_VAR` with the output of the execution of the `ls -l *` command that is taken from the rest of the arguments.  However, if the command was to output empty lines at the end, (for e.g. `- echo -e -n '\n\n123\n456\n789\n\n'` which should have 2 x new lines at the start and the end ) these are stripped by bash's sub-execution process.  I have seen in other posts similar to this that this has been solved by adding a token 'x' to the end of the stream, e.g. turning the sub-execution into something like:

```
eval ${STORE_INvar}=\""$( "$@" 2>&1 ; echo -n x )"\" # <-- ( Add echo -n x )
# and then if it wasn't an indirect reference to a var:
STORE_INvar=${STORE_INvar%x} 
# However no matter how much I play with:
eval "${STORE_INvar}"=\""${STORE_INvar%x}"\"  
# I am unable to indirectly remove the x from the end.
```

Anyway, I also need 2 x other variants on this, one that assigns the `STDIN stream` to the var and one that assigns the contents of a file to the var which I assume will be variations of this involving `$( cat ${1} )`, or maybe `$( cat ${1:--} )` to give me a '-' if no filename.  But, none of that will work until I can sort out the removal of the x that is needed to ensure accurate assignment of multi line variables.

I have also tried (but to no avail):

```
IFS='' read -d '' "${STORE_INvar}" <<<"$( $@ ; echo -n x )"
eval \"'${STORE_INvar}=${!STORE_INvar%x}'\"
```

Comment: As an aside, `echo -e` is non-POSIX, meaning any shell implementing it as doing anything other than printing a line containing the two characters `-` and `e` is not extending the specification, but breaking it outright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close to optimal -- but drop the `eval`.

```
executeToVar() { local varName=$1; shift; printf -v "$1" %s "$("$@")"; }
```

The one problem this formulation still has is that `$()` strips trailing newlines. If you want to prevent that, you need to add your own trailing character inside the subshell, and strip it off yourself.

```
executeToVar() {
  local varName=$1; shift;
  local val="$(printf %s x; "$@"; printf %s x)"; val=${val#x}
  printf -v "$varName" %s "${val%x}"
}
```

---

If you want to read all content from stdin into a variable, this is particularly easy:

```
# This requires bash 4.1 for automatic fd allocation
readToVar() {
  if [[ $2 && $2 != "-" ]]; then
    exec {read_in_fd}<"$2"              # copy from named file
  else
    exec {read_in_fd}<&0                # copy from stdin
  fi
  IFS= read -r -d '' "$1" <&$read_in_fd # read from the FD
  exec {read_in_fd}<&-                  # close that FD
}
```

...used as:

```
readToVar var < <( : "run something here to read its output byte-for-byte" )
```

...or...

```
readToVar var filename
```

---

Testing these:

```
bash3-3.2$ executeToVar var printf '\n\n123\n456\n789\n\n'
bash3-3.2$ declare -p var
declare -- var="

123
456
789

"
```

...and...

```
bash4-4.3$ readToVar var2 < <(printf '\n\n123\n456\n789\n\n')
bash4-4.3$ declare -p var2
declare -- var2="

123
456
789

"
```

Answer (score 0):

what'w wrong with storing in a file:

```
   $ stuffToFile filename $(stuff)
```

where "stuffToFile" tests for a. > 1 argument, b. input on a pipe

```
   $ ... commands ... | stuffToFile filename
```

and

```
   $ stuffToFile filename < another_file
```

where "stoffToFile" is a function:

```
function stuffToFile
{
    [[ -f $1 ]] || { echo $1 is not a file; return 1; }

    [[ $# -lt 2 ]] && { cat - > $1; return; }

    echo "$*" > $1
}
```

so, if "stuff" has leading and trailing blank lines, then you must:

```
   $ stuff | stuffToFile filename
```

Comment: To start with, `echo` will drop your content if all your program outputs is the two-character string `-n` -- or that string with newlines following.

Comment: Also, you need to quote your `$1` expansion in `> $1`, or this will crash when given filenames with spaces.

Comment: Similarly, `$(stuff)` needs to be `"$(stuff)"` to avoid glob expansion and string-splitting, and that still doesn't avoid the trailing-whitespace discarding behavior the OP wishes to avoid.

Comment: let me be a little snippy:  when i find people are using spaces in file names, then i might consider modifying, but , and  the real comment for the OP is that all these modes are never collapsed into the same function is they are fundamentally different.  i.e.  the last    $ stuff > filename   is sufficient.  and then, one asks how is the text being used?  treating a shell variable as potentially multi-line seems to be counter to it's use.

Comment: The OP *explicitly* gives assignment of a multi-line value in their question as something they want to be able to do with byte-for-byte accuracy. That's the `echo -e -n '\n\n123\n456\n789\n\n'` example.

Comment: @user4838443, making the pipe case work would open up a rat's nest of security issues, since it would mean that you'd need content to be eval'd. Much better not to bother -- see the examples I gave using process substitution, the `<()` syntax, to feed input from a subshell running arbitrary code.

Comment: The problem is that I need a command that sits at the end of a normal pipeline.  Can I not do this with file descriptors?  Maybe using an alias to assign a FD mapping to the end of the command and then execute a helper function that takes the name of the variable and streams from that FD into it?  I assumed that wouldn't be to hard, but cannot get it to work and I much prefer that to the alternative of having to grab the last line from history and execute it in the < ( ) style syntax.  The problem I get is that I cannot setup either side to a new FD as until its assigned it moans about this.