# Can I avoid using a FIFO file to join the end of a Bash pipeline to be stored in a variable in the current shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

I have the following functions:

```
execIn ()
{
    local STORE_INvar="${1}" ; shift
    printf -v "${STORE_INvar}" '%s' "$( eval "$@" ; printf %s x ; )"
    printf -v "${STORE_INvar}" '%s' "${!STORE_INvar%x}"
}
```

and

```
getFifo ()
{
    local FIFOfile
    FIFOfile="/tmp/diamondLang-FIFO-$$-${RANDOM}"
    while [ -e "${FIFOfile}" ]
    do
        FIFOfile="/tmp/diamondLang-FIFO-$$-${RANDOM}"
    done
    mkfifo "${FIFOfile}"
    echo "${FIFOfile}"
}
```

I want to store the output of the end of a pipeline into a variable as given to a function at the end of the pipeline, however, the only way I have found to do this that will work in early versions of Bash is to use mkfifo to make a temp fifo file.  I was hoping to use file descriptors to avoid having to create temporary files.  So, This works, but is not ideal:

Set Up: (before I can do this I need to have assigned a FIFO file to a var that can be used by the rest of the process)

```
$ FIFOfile="$( getFifo )"
```

The Pipeline I want to persist:

```
$ printf '\n\n123\n456\n524\n789\n\n\n' | grep 2  # for e.g.
```

The action: (I can now add) `>${FIFOfile} &`

```
$ printf '\n\n123\n456\n524\n789\n\n\n' | grep 2 >${FIFOfile} &
```

N.B. The need to background it with & - Problem 1: I get `[1] <PID_NO>` output to the screen.

The actual persist:

```
$ execIn SOME_VAR cat - <${FIFOfile}
```

Problem 2: I get more noise to the screen

```
[1]+  Done  printf '\n\n123\n456\n524\n789\n\n\n' | grep 2 > ${FIFOfile}
```

Problem 3: I loose the blanks at the start of the stream rather than at the end as I have experienced before.

So, am I doing this the right way?  I am sure that there must be a way to avoid the need of a FIFO file that needs cleanup afterwards using file descriptors, but I cannot seem to do this as I cannot assign either side of the problem to a file descriptor that is not attached to a file or a FIFO file.

I can try and resolve the problems with what I have, although to make this work properly I guess I need to pre-establish a pool of FIFO files that can be pulled in to use or else I have a pre-req of establishing this file before the command.  So, for many reasons this is far from ideal.  If anyone can advise me of a better way you would make my day/week/month/life :)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Ideally what I am desperately striving to achieve is a simple command that takes one argument: the VAR_NAME to set with the data that is received from Standard In.  e.g. to be used in the following construction:
`$ printf '\n\n123\n456\n524\n789\n\n\n' | grep 2 | myCommand THE_VAR_TO_USE` but know that this is not possible using conventional implementation due to the sub-shell issue and the fix in Bash 4 does not work for me as I need to support earlier versions of Bash :(

Comment: That "noise to the screen" (Problem 1 and Problem 2) should only happen with job control turned on -- which is the default in an interactive session, but **not** in a script. Do you really have all three problems in scripts?

Comment: Also -- if you're using a FIFO for backwards compatibility, could you specify **exactly** how old of a release you need to be compatible with?

Comment: Also, what's with the `eval "$@"`? Generally, that's a bad idea -- unless you **really** need shell constructs to be expanded in your arguments, you should just run `"$@"`, not `eval "$@"`, and avoid the substantial security risks. I believe the answer where I gave you `execIn` did not include that `eval`, and very intentionally so.

Comment: For anyone wanting to follow along -- this question is a continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900839/how-do-i-indirectly-assign-a-variable-in-bash-to-take-multi-line-data-from-both

Comment: I absolutely as a minimum need to work with Bash v2 although I do have some Bash 1 systems and some posix bourne systems that I will need to make work with things like this at some point so I am really trying to make a solution out of lowest common denominator constructs, ideally POSIX that can be used everywhere.  However, I appreciate that this is not always possible so Bash 2 would be great.

Comment: The "noise to the screen" thing as you say might be less of an issue if non interactive, although, its more the fact that the method has a pre-req of having to create a fifo file first, that makes implementation of a self-contained function imposable (unless you can suggest how?).  TBH, if I can somehow encapsulate that process into a command that takes an arg, the var to assign, even if via some nasty alias hack, that would be great!  I just cannot work the construction of that out! :(

Comment: Re: the eval, I would love to avoid the eval situation, unfortunately, as some of the commands that need to be passed to it include a pipeline of commands, it was the only way I could work of doing this.  Again, if you can suggest a way I can avoid eval and still pass arguments such as: `"printf '\n\n123\n456\n524\n789\n\n\n' | grep 2"` then that would be amazing!

Comment: My answer already does that, and has since I first wrote it. `readToVar targetVar < <(printf '\n\n123\n456\n524\n789\n\n\n' | grep 2)`

Comment: There is no such thing as "POSIX Bourne"; the POSIX specification was written long, long after the Bourne shell was written, and patterned off of early ksh -- thus, specifying a great many features that Bourne does not provide. Perhaps you mean "POSIX sh"?

Comment: Probably :) I was sure it is called Bourne shell.  I work with a bunch of legacy Sun Sparc's that have SunOS from v7-10.  They all use /bin/sh as their shell/used everywhere runtime interpreter.  Don't think they have any vars that start BASH_xyz so I thought it was Bourne shell.  I have seen stuff in the man pages about Posix, hence Posix Bourne - I will check and work out for sure. Problem with them is, they get patched, minor upgrades when the patches absolutely demand it, and thats about it so they are like using machines form the 80's! :(

Comment: Legacy SunOS systems from the era you're referring to ship with non-POSIX-compliant Bourne. (POSIX sh was developed as a specification in the early 90s; I want to say '91).

Comment: To easily distinguish, by the way -- if the `^` character works as a pipe, you're dealing with a Bourne shell, not a POSIX sh shell.

Answer (score 2):

Process substitution was available in bash from the ancient days. You absolutely **do not** have a version so ancient as to be unable to use it. Thus, there's no need to use a FIFO at all:

```
readToVar() { IFS= read -r -d '' "$1"; }
readToVar targetVar < <(printf '\n\n123\n456\n524\n789\n\n\n')
```

You'll observe that:

```
printf '%q\n' "$targetVar"
```

...correctly preserves the leading newlines as well as the trailing ones.

---

By contrast, in a use case where you can't afford to lose stdin:

```
readToVar() { IFS= read -r -d '' "$1" <"$2"; }
readToVar targetVar <(printf '\n\n123\n456\n524\n789\n\n\n')
```

---

If you **really** want to pipe to this command, are willing to require a very modern bash, and don't mind being incompatible with job control:

```
set +m            # disable job control
shopt -s lastpipe # in a pipeline, parent shell becomes right-hand side

readToVar() { IFS= read -r -d '' "$1"; }
printf '\n\n123\n456\n524\n789\n\n\n' | grep 2 | readToVar targetVar
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use process substitution as I have to operate at the end of a pipeline, unless there is a way of using it inside a command I put at the end of the pipeline, so that the interaction with the user is still `myCommand myVariableToStreamTo`, however I couldn't work a way of doing that without it turning into what feels like a giant hack as I was tail -1 the bash history file, etc.

Comment: Edited to demonstrate use of this mechanism without overriding stdin, thus allowing usage within a pipeline or other context where stdin must be preserved.

Comment: If that's still not good enough, I'd argue that you need to do a better job of describing your actual use case.

Comment: I apologise if I have not done a good job at defining the use case.  Originally on another question I tried asking the actual whole problem, although did not get many responses, I assumed as it was too abstract.  I am striving to end up with the ability to issue a simple command (be it a function, executable, alias assignment, whatever) that allows the end of a pipe to be appended with it and given one argument, e.g. `$ printf '\n\n123\n456\n524\n789\n\n\n' | grep 2 | theNewCommand THE_VAR_TO_SET`, I am totally happy to use proc sub if I can somehow encapsulate it to be exec'd via this method.

Comment: The best-practices answer is to structure it the other way! Why do you want to run `printf '\n\n123\n456\n524\n789\n\n\n' | grep 2 | theNewCommand THE_VAR_TO_SET` rather than `theNewCommand THE_VAR_TO_SET < <(printf '\n\n123\n456\n524\n789\n\n\n' | grep 2)`? Is there any actual real and substantial difference, beyond aesthetics of the code?

Comment: I am trying to piece together a lot of the many tools and tricks I have used over the years to provide a library for bash that can be sourced into your shell that not only simplifies some of the language but also provides consistency where in the past there has been variation, e.g. echo -e, on systems that do not support it, I override it so when writing a script you don't need to worry about the differences.  On the nice to have side, when I am teaching new scripters, they always hate the methods for assigning values to variables from non simple sources, so, I am trying to simplify this task:

Comment: Again, `eval "$@"` is evil. If you *must* eval, use `eval "$1"` and only accept a single string argument for that case -- at least you're being explicit about your semantics that way. Or `for x; eval "$x"; done`.

Comment: BTW, `printf -v` doesn't meet your portability requirements either.

Comment: BTW, in terms of writing a shell library that papers over portability issues, you wouldn't be the first person to do that. I'd tend to suggest reusing battle-tested code by someone who knows where the corner cases are rather than trying to roll your own. Submitting patches to one of the existing libraries also means that your code will be reviewed by someone else before it gets merged, which would be worthwhile as well.

Comment: see: https://github.com/major0/shlib (explicitly portable); https://github.com/lhunath/scripts/blob/master/bashlib/bashlib (focused on bash).

Comment: I have 3 use cases I am trying to deal with, 2 of which I believe are solved; 1) A function that takes a VAR to assign to and executes the rest of its args into that var, 2) A function that takes a list a VAR to assign to and one or more filenames to stream into it, and 3) a function (or command of sorts) that can be placed at the end of a pipeline and be invoked in a similar way, i.e. `command VAR_NAME_TO_SET`, I then wanted to combine all three with some tests that detect the context of use so that a simple "super-command" such as "into" can do all three depending on its context.

Comment: Bad idea. What if the user wants to run a filename as a command? How do you tell what your argument should be treated as? Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments, they are really appreciated, re: printf, :( oh no!  That was my saviour, I thought printf was in all versions of bash, is that not the case?  I will have to make a similar function if need be, wrap awk's printf or something.  I have done this a lot and have a pattern where I have alternative functions that get pulled in depending on the version and restrictions of what you have available to you in your shell.

Comment: `printf` is defined in POSIX. The `-v` argument is not.

Comment: I was going to have the three separate functions to be used explicitly if need be and a super function that first tests if the stdin is a terminal to decide if a pipe, then if all args after first are files that can be read, to decide the rest.  BTW, would you mind expanding on why wrapping the eval in an `for x; eval "${x}"; done` is more safe?  Really appreciate the help!

Comment: It's not inherently safer; what it is is **explicit**. That is to say: If you use it in a way that means you don't know your content is being eval'd, it will fail. Thus, the user is forced to **know** that they need to take appropriate cautions for `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

The issues you claim to run into with using a FIFO do not actually exist. Put this **in a script**, and run it:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'rm -rf "$tempdir"' 0 # cleanup on exit
tempdir=$(mktemp -d -t fifodir.XXXXXX)
mkfifo "$tempdir/fifo"

printf '\n\n123\n456\n524\n789\n\n\n' >"$tempdir/fifo" &
IFS= read -r -d '' content <"$tempdir/fifo"
printf '%q\n' "$content" # print content to console
```

You'll notice that, when run in a script, there is no "noise" printed to the screen, because all that status is explicitly tied to job control, which is disabled by default in scripts.

You'll also notice that both leading and tailing newlines are correctly represented.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I do intend to allow my library to be used interactively too, but, from what you say guess that all I need to do is disable job control for the duration of the execution?  You don't happen to know if there is a easy way to disable job control and restore to previous setting do you?

Comment: Easiest way to suppress the messages is actually to run your background jobs in a subshell: `( printf '\n\n123\n456\n524\n789\n\n\n' >"$tempdir/fifo" & )`

Comment: Thankyou!!  I am away now trying to a) try this as is, and b) split it and munge into an alias/function/something to see if I can get it to work in my `$ cmd1 | cmd2 | myCommand ARG_NAME_TO_SET` context, wish me luck!! :)  Thanks again for all the help!!  Its APPRECIATED SO MUCH!! :-D

Comment: Personally, my guess would be that the only thing I'd think of you could use there would be a DEBUG trap with extdebug enabled, and that's about the least portable thing possible.

Answer (score 0):

One idea, tell me I am crazy, might be to use the !! notation to grab the line just executed, e.g. if there is a command that can terminate a pipeline and stop it actually executing, whilst still as far as the shell is concerned, consider it as a successful execution, I am thinking something like the `true` command, I could then use !! to grab that line and call my existing function to execute it with process substitution or something.  I could then wrap this into an alias, something like: `alias streamTo=' | true ; LAST_EXEC="!!" ; myNewCommandVariation <<<'` which I *think* could be used something like: `$ cmd1 | cmd2 | myNewCommandVariation THE_VAR_NAME_TO_SET` and the <<< from the alias would pass the var name to the command as an arg or stdin, either way, the command would be not at the end of a pipeline.  How mad is this idea?

Comment: History expansion only works by default in interactive shells, not scripts. Turning it on in scripts would be putting you into codepaths that... are not often used or tested.

Comment: Same for aliases -- they're not available in scripts by default.

Comment: Also, since aliases are prefix substitution with no quoting awareness, one would need to be *exceedingly* cautious of quoting bugs.

Comment: Interesting, I have had to use alias tricks a few times so far so one of the first things my library does is to `shopt -s expand_aliases` do you know of any issue this might cause?  For e.g. two I use a lot are, `alias testArgs='[ "$#" -gt "0" ] ;'` and `alias shiftLast='set -- "${@:1:$(($#-1))}"' ; ` so I can say `while testArgs ; do blahh ; done ; ` and so as well as the `shift` command I have `shiftLast` to operate on the other side when needed.  I obviously try to avoid these weirder uses if I can, but so nice to have when you need them!

Comment: Those are both legitimate uses of aliases.

Comment: What would you do, if you had to chose one of the two approaches?  The mkfifo route or the history route implemented with a store, unset and restore of the history expansion setting?  Which are the least of the two evils? :)

Comment: The mkfifo route, definitely. That's something people have been doing for decades when they want a POSIX-compatible alternative to process substitution.

Comment: Re: legitimate uses: few!  Thats good to know, for a second I was worried some key blocks of my new nicer world were a bad practice for some reason I was unaware of!! :-)  Thanks for confirming!!  Charles Duffy, I think I owe you some beers and an Amazon voucher or two :)  you have given so much kind help!!  It is really appreciated!! :-)

Answer (score -1):

Not a full answer but rather a first point: is there some good reason not using `mktemp` for creating a new file with a random name? As far as I can see, your function called `getFifo()` doesn't perform much more.

```
mktemp -u
```

will give to you a free new name without creating anything; then you can use `mkfifo` with this name.

Comment: The getFifo function above already finds and generates a temp fifo file, creating the temp file is not the issue, unfortunately - as that is one I could resolve! :-)  The issue is being able to stream the end of a pipeline into a variable that is normally lost due to the fact that each pipeline component normally operates within their own sub-shells.  I am trying to join up a somewhat convoluted multi-step implementation to result in a simple command that can be appended to the end of a pipeline, one that takes a single var which is the name of the variable to store the contents of the pipe.

Comment: I understand this is not the main issue but I am still asking why you are not using a well-known and standard tool for that part of the job. Regards.